# Remove key value pair in JSON data

Tags: c, json, string

I'm very new to C and I'm working with JSON data which is of type char *. For example:

```
{"string": "some string","text": "some text","name": "some name","data": "some data"}
```

I need to delete one of the key value pairs in my json object. For example, I would like to remove "text": "some text" so my object will look like:

```
 {"string": "some string","name": "some name","data": "some data"}
```

What is the best way to do this? Is there a library for this?

Could I possibly use substring?

Comment: sorry i updated

Comment: You can break the string into tokens with `strtok`, and then copy the strings you want to keep into a new buffer with `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: You should decide whether its justified to add a library to your project. If its important or you'll be doing other json manipulation, then it is worth it. You should google for json libraries. If its a one off and a library increases complexity/ reduces performance then you could just go ahead and manipulate the string directly.